# Dynamically load jquery in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, scripting

I am taking a page that does not have jquery referenced in the dom. I need to use some of the jquery functionality, so i figured the best bet is to inject jquery into the existing dom. I got the function idea from [Load jQuery with Javascript and use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery) and  [How to include jQuery dynamically in any website using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442462/how-to-include-jquery-dynamically-in-any-website-using-pure-javascript) ....none of these solutions seem to work for me. I am still getting an error not recognizing the jquery selector.

```
(function() {
    function getScript(url, success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            done = false;
        // Attach handlers for all browsers
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (!done && (!this.readyState
               || this.readyState == 'loaded'
               || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
            done = true;
            success();
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);
          }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js',function() {
        // Yay jQuery is ready \o/
    });                         


    cards = $('div:first');
    $('body').empty().append(cards);

    // Delete first and second child divs

    first = $('div:first div:first');
    $('div:first div:first').css('position', '').css('left', '').css('z-index', '').css('height', '250px').remove();

    second = $('div:first div:first');
    $('div:first div:first').css('position', 'relative').css('left', '').css('z-index', '').remove();

    $('body').empty().append(first).append(second);
    })();
```

Comment: You're supposed to move your own code into the callback, to where it says `// Yay...`. Only then is your code run *after* jQuery was loaded.

Comment: wel;l thats embarrassing...feel free to answer and ill accept

Comment: There is no such property "onreadystatechange" on script element, I think it is misleading information, just "onload" is enough. Here answer from Chris G is acceptable. Here is the plunker for the same https://plnkr.co/edit/WYV7PQDX9wJTjnVfQENa?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to move your own code into the callback, to where it says // Yay.... Only then is your code run *after* jQuery was loaded.

```
getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js', function() {
    // Yay jQuery is ready \o/

    $('body').empty().append($('div:first'));
    // Delete first and second child divs
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $('div:first div:first').remove();
    }
});
```